# ng-hide & ng-show not working only in a particular AngularJS page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-hide

For the device's details view page Im building, I have used Angular's **ng-show** and **ng-hide** directives to alter the buttons display according to the device status color. I get the color from the database using {{item.transaction_Mode}}. The Angular part does seem to work as it outputs 'true' and 'false' correctly but when it combines with the ng-show like ng-show='true' it doesn't work.

**HTML code :-**

Color generation part -

```
<div  style="width: 30%; float: left">
                    <div ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'red'}}" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: red;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <div ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: orange;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <div ng-hide="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'red'}} || {{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: green;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <h1  style="text-align: left">{{devices[whichItem].name}} - [id  {{devices[whichItem].device_ID}}] </h1>
</div>
```

Button display according to color part -

```
<div  style="width: 70%; float: left; "> 


                   <button ng-hide="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'red'}} || {{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" style="margin-top:  20px; width: 17%; float: left; height: 46px;" type="button" data-target="modal1" class="Now waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" >Now</button>
                    <p style="width: 3%; float: left"> </p>
                    <button  style="margin-top:  20px; width: 17%; float: left; height: 46px;" type="button" data-target="modal2" class="Later waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger ">Later</button>
                    <p style="width: 3%; float: left"> </p>
                    <button ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" style="margin-top:  20px; width: 17%; float: left; height: 46px;" type="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn " >Get</button>
                    <p style="width: 3%; float: left"> </p>
                    <button ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" style="margin-top:  20px; width: 17%; float: left; height: 46px; " type="button" data-target="modal4" class="Cancel waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" >Cancel</button>
                    <p style="width: 3%; float: left"> </p>
                    <button ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'red'}}" style="margin-top:  20px; width: 17%; float: left; height: 46px; " type="button" data-target="modal3" class="Return waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" >Return</button>

</div>
```

But this same code works for another two pages and I cant understand why it doesn't for this.
ng-if or ng-switch-when doesn't work either.
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you included the controller on this page as well?

Comment: try to use `ng-if` to overcome it.!

Comment: Do you have a CSS style that makes those element visible? `ngShow` and `ngHide` use `display: none`

Comment: Remove the curly braces. For ex: Change ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" to ng-show="item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'"

Comment: My controller is as below -                                                 homeCtrls.controller('detailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $http.get('webapi/devices').success(function (data) {
            $scope.devices = data;
            $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
        });

Comment: 'ng-if' also doesn't work @Kunalhttp

Answer (score 0):

Typo mistake. ng-if, ng-show don't requires {{}} to bind to $scope data.

So,

```
<div  style="width: 30%; float: left">
                    <div ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'red'}}" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: red;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <div ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: orange;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <div ng-hide="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'red'}} || {{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: green;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <h1  style="text-align: left">{{devices[whichItem].name}} - [id  {{devices[whichItem].device_ID}}] </h1>
</div>
```

SHOULD BE:

```
<div  style="width: 30%; float: left">
                    <div ng-show="item.transaction_Mode == 'red'" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: red;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <div ng-show="item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: orange;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <div ng-hide="item.transaction_Mode == 'red' || item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'" class="col s1 m1 l1 vertical-line" style="height: 100%;width: 10px; background-color: green;float: left; " > </div>     
                    <h1  style="text-align: left">{{devices[whichItem].name}} - [id  {{devices[whichItem].device_ID}}] </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks but this doesn't solve my problem. I have used {{ }} because I have defined the variable item and get the transaction_Mode (color) relevant to each item from the front end, so can directly use it. The Angular expression does output the correct answer as in 'true' or 'false' but when it comes with ng-show / ng-hide, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ng-show="{{item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'}}"
```

Use:

```
ng-show="item.transaction_Mode == 'orange'"
```

Comment: Hey thanks but this doesn't solve my problem. I have used {{ }} because I have defined the variable item and get the transaction_Mode (color) relevant to each item from the front end, so can directly use it. The Angular expression does output the correct answer as in 'true' or 'false' but when it comes with ng-show / ng-hide, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs directives, like ng-show or ng-hide don't need using {{}}.

Comment: Hey thanks but this doesn't solve my problem. I have used {{ }} because I have defined the variable item and get the transaction_Mode (color) relevant to each item from the front end, so can directly use it. The Angular expression does output the correct answer as in 'true' or 'false' but when it comes with ng-show / ng-hide, it doesn't work.